# Leaf images rotated wrong way on Sapling tree Gen

Tags: texturing, uv, objects

I made plant using curve > Sapling tree Gen. But the leaves are placed in wrong directions. How to fix it and make it right?

[image: tree with alpha mapped leaves]

Comment: Try to rotate UV map

Comment: Set the origin of base-leaf at the petiole of leaf.

Answer (score 1):

Well depending on what option you picked when you made the leaves for the tree you will have to fix this differently.

For both *Rectangular* and *Hexagonal* you will need to edit the UV map for the leaf object.

For the cube leaf the key is to get the stem of the leaf to line up on the bottom of the UVs *in the center*.
In the case of the Hexagonal leaf you want the bottom point of the hexagon to be right on the stem.
[image: UV mapping the leaves]
When you have the UVs set up that way the stem of the leaf will be right on the branch. If the leaf is not in the correct orientation from the branch you need to rotate the UVs. Start by rotating the UVs by 90° then see which way you need to go. (A UV Image Editor *and* 3D view open helps immensely here.)

---

For the DupliVert or DupliFaces options it is easier, you only need to align the origin of the leaf object onto the stem. A picture does a better job of explaining it:
[image: Leaf object in edit mode]
Remember here you are moving the object in edit mode.